# How to smoothly connect a circle with rectangle shape at the tangent?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to connect a rectangle with a circle at its tangent in illustrator. The problem is – and i hope you can see it in the image – that the transition is not very smooth and quit ugly.

How can you get a smoother transition like here: [image: Helvetica J]

and not like this:

[image: Circle + Rectangle]

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: As the answer below states, doing this kind of work is always done easiest, when the objects to be joined are oriented vertically or horizontally.  _Then_ you rotate the entire object, after joining the paths.

Comment: Related and possible duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16598/how-to-draw-circle-tangents-and-removing-the-inner-lines

Comment: @Vincent that question doesn't actually talk about making the tangent lines, just dealing with the unwanted paths *after* making the tangents. You should know, you answered it ;)

Comment: I had a script that did this nicely. I'll have a look and see if I can post it when I'm back at a computer

Comment: @CAI A long time ago :P

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making the rectangle completely vertical (not at an angle). Line up the bottom right corner of the rectangle with the far right point of the circle and combine them. Then rotate the whole shape.

[image: Connect shapes smoothly]

Comment: You are right, but I would suggest you improve your answer, by adding pictures.